# python - Why does this Project Euler #3 solution work?

Tags: python

I recently finished the [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) [problem, number 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3), which says:

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

I was looking at other people's solutions to this, when I came across this one.

```
n = 600851475143  
i = 2

while i * i < n:
    while n%i == 0:
        n = n / i
    i = i + 1

 print (n)
```

Now, I know that this program works, but I have no idea why it works at all. Could someone explain this for me?

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: @Christian - TO be honest, I don't think I understand any of it. Why would you loop until i*i <n, why do you keep constantly dividing while n % i == 0. Those kind of things

Comment: I think this is more a mathematics problem than a programming one. Therefore, you should ask it in [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Since you finished it yourself too, could you share your solution? That way, we can see how you approached the problem and then try to explain the similarities and differences.

Comment: I agree, this is math, specifically the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So looking at the program, it appears to get all prime factors of `n` and return the largest one. Let's go over it one line at a time:

```
while i * i < n:
```

This particular piece of code looks like a mistake at first, but it works when you realize that `n` is continually growing smaller. The program is using repeated division to reduce `n` to its largest prime factor.

```
while n%i == 0:
```

The operation `n % i` returns the remainder of `n / i`. So if `n % i == 0`, then the current value of `i` can evenly divide into `n`, i.e. `i` is a factor of `n`.

```
n = n / i
```

Here, we are continually dividing `n` by `i`; we will keep doing this division until the `while` condition is no longer true. We need to divide as many times as we can, as this has the effect of removing any possible composite factors. If our given number was 24, for example, we would divide it by 2 three times, eventually making `n` equal to 3. This eliminates any possible composite factors that are a multiple of 2.

```
i = i + 1
```

Increment our number and repeat.

This works well because, by using `n = n / i` repeatedly, we are removing successively larger prime factors from `n`. The more of these prime factors we eliminate, the smaller `n` gets, until it is eventually indivisible by anything except 1. At this point, `n` is equal to the largest prime factor of the original number, and so we return it.

Now our stopping condition makes more sense, as well. At the time when `n` becomes prime (the largest prime factor), then there is no value of `i` we can produce that will be evenly divisible. We will know this when `i * i` is greater than `n` - if you have a composite number, then one of the factors is necessarily `>= n^1/2`.

As mentioned by Ionut Hulub, this specific solution will fail if `n` is any perfect square. As a safeguard against this, you should print out both `n` and the largest `i` that evenly divided the number.

Comment: You can get the right result always if you change the first `while` condition to `i*i <= n` and then print `i-1` instead of `n` at the end if `n == 1`. This works for squares, cubes and any other numbers with their largest prime factor repeated.

Answer (score 1):

That solution is incorrect.

It fails when n is the square of a prime number (for example: 4, 9, 25...), so explaining how it works would be useless cause it doesn't work.

Comment: it does work for the problem

Comment: It works for that instance of the problem, but not for the problem. In other words, it is useless.

Comment: There is only one instance of Euler problem 3, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: This solution requires prior knowledge that the given number is not a perfect square. So it's correct, but not a great solution.

Comment: The problem is to make a program that finds the largest prime factor of a number. The instance is to find the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143. In practice, you want to solve problems, not instances. So although project euler will accept the above solution, you should looks for a better one if you want to learn programming.

Comment: @IonutHulub not true. The problem is to make a program that finds the largest prime factor of 600851475143. It does not say to solve the general case. This does work and solves for the correct answer. Edge cases exist, but that doesn't make the solution incorrect when the edge case doesn't apply.

Comment: Not any number, a particular number that you know before you write the solution.

Comment: @AdamSmith It depends how you look at it I suppose. But you know what they say: `evan a broken clock is right twice a day`. I don't think beginner programmers should learn to code based on that saying.

Comment: @IonutHulub yes but by your definition, NO FUNCTION no matter how limited in scope can ever be technically correct if it cannot function correctly given arbitrary input.

Comment: @AdamSmith: it's basically as correct as an answer that just hard coded the answer and didn't calculate anything.

Comment: @Wooble I don't know. This answer does work. It has an edge case (essentially an off-by-one error) but it's not on the same level as hardcoding the answer.

Comment: @AdamSmith So where do you draw the line then? How many edge cases is a function allowed to have and still be considered correct?

Comment: @IonutHulub if I needed a function to read from a file and perform some `foo` on the contents, I wouldn't care if it threw up on an empty file if I could otherwise guarantee that the file was not empty. Similarly, this function throws up if given a perfect square, however we can guarantee that the input will not be a perfect square. That's a working answer as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @IonutHulub similarly, I would definitely NOT call this solution correct if the task was to create a function that finds the greatest prime factor of its input.

Comment: @AdamSmith I feel like understanding edge cases and how to program around them is vital for when somebody is learning how to code. Once you have a good understanding of them and you're working in a non-theoretical setting, that's when I would start doing things like planning for certain kinds of input.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense agreed, and I wouldn't laud this as great code, but for the problem at-hand it is, in fact, correct.